# how to fill dataframe with former value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I import the data from an excel file. But the format of merged cells in excel file does not match in python. Therefore, I have to modify the data in python.

for example: the data I import in python looks like

```
0   aa
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   b
5   NaN
6   NaN
7   NaN
8   NaN
9   ccc
10  NaN
11  NaN
12  NaN
13  dd
14  NaN
15  NaN
16  NaN
```

the result I want is:

```
0   aa
1   aa
2   aa
3   aa
4   b
5   b
6   b
7   b
8   b
9   ccc
10  ccc
11  ccc
12  ccc
13  dd
14  dd
15  dd
16  dd
```

I tried to use for loop to fix the problem. But it took lots of time and I have a huge dataset. I do not know if there is a faster way to do it.

Comment: You're loading your data to a `pandas` dataframe, right?

Comment: the data type should be string instead of float, sorry about that

Comment: If you have an addition to your question, it's best to edit the question and add it there, not in a comment.

Comment: @Itamar Mushkin   yes

Comment: To convert the type - `df = df.astype(str)`

Comment: @Itamar Mushkin I have modified the picture for better understanding my question, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [`.fillna()` is your friend](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) – quoting the documentation::

> We can also propagate non-null values forward or backward.

```
>>> df
     A    B   C  D
0  NaN  2.0 NaN  0
1  3.0  4.0 NaN  1
2  NaN  NaN NaN  5
3  NaN  3.0 NaN  4
>>> df.fillna(method='ffill')
    A   B   C   D
0   NaN 2.0 NaN 0
1   3.0 4.0 NaN 1
2   3.0 4.0 NaN 5
3   3.0 3.0 NaN 4
```

Comment: Ah, beat me to it :-)

Comment: @AKX can you please help me revise the question format again?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the use of the `.fillna()` function in `pandas`

Answer (score 0):

You can get your desired result with the help of `apply` AND `fillna` methods :-

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'A':['a', np.nan, np.nan, 'b', np.nan]})

l = []
def change(value): 
    if value == "bhale":
        value = l[-1]
        return value
    else:        
        l.append(value)
        return value

# First converting NaN values into any string value like `bhale` here
df['A'] = df['A'].fillna('bhale')  
df["A"] = df['A'].apply(change)   # Using apply method.
df
```

I hope it may help you.